# Use YouTube channels as podcast in iTunes

Tags: itunes, rss, youtube, podcasts

Is there a way to subscribe to a YouTube channel and have it show up in iTunes as a podcast? I want iTunes to automatically download the videos in MP4 format or download them in FLV and convert them to MP4 in iPod format.

Answer (score 3):

You may try to use [Podsync](http://podsync.net). It converts YouTube/Vimeo links (groups, channels, users) to podcast feeds, which can be added to any podcast player on iOS/Android or whatever platform you use. It's completely free and easy to use.
And you don't need to download an app.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Added brief description on how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you want but [Miro](http://www.getmiro.com/) does a pretty good job of consolidating Youtube downloads and Video podcasts. Not sure if you can get it to serve up a podcast of what it's downloaded though.

Also noticed this http://vixy.net/podcaster/ haven't tried it though.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to get Miro to subscribe to a YouTube channel. I tried using the RSS url and also the URL of the channel page.

Answer (score 1):

I tried http://vixy.net/podcaster/ but their server seems to be having problems right now.

I did not solve my problem exactly the way I wanted to but this solution is pretty close.

I am using [Tooble](http://tooble.tv/) which will download and convert YouTube videos. It even has a place where you can enter a YouTube users' username and it will show all videos in their channel. Then the trick to get the videos automatically added to iTunes was to configure it to save all videos to `C:\Users\MyUsername\Music\iTunes\iTunes Media\Automatically Add to iTunes`

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Tubecaster](http://unbouncepages.com/tubecaster/).

It's still in open beta, but just did the job.

Answer (score 0):

This question haunted me as well, and all the available options either didn't work or didn't fit... So I made my own: [YouCast](http://youcast.i3arnon.com/)

- It's free and open sourced.
- It works for both channels and playlists.
- Supports both audio and video podcasts.
- Sorts by popularity.

Comment: Does it require to keep app running all the time?

Comment: @rapt0r yes, well as long as you want to update your feeds. I'm working on a hosted version but it takes time and has its problems.

Answer (score 0):

The same question haunted me three years ago when I wanted to listen some youtube channels during commuting. My first thought was "youtubers should create their podcasts, it is so easy to get the mp3 from a video, then upload it, then update a feed, then host it ... and all of this every day/week/month ...

Non, finally it's not that easy. So, as a podcast lover and a backend developer,  I created a service which is doing exactly this.

Converting episodes from a youtube channel into audio files and hosting updated feed and audio files.

Now, for youtube channel owner it's quite easy to get one podcast up to date with every episodes. The name of it is [Podmytube](https://www.podmytube.com/).

You can try it freely. You only need to create an account and register your channel.
Hope this help.

Answer (score -1):

[Listenbox](https://listenbox.app/) does this. It converts videos, channels and playlists to podcasts and takes care of the updates